# Class getName() behavior in aspect vs instance method

Tags: java, spring, reflection, aop

In a Spring 3 webapp, I have a DAO that looks something like this:

```
public class BaseDAOImpl<T extends AbstractEntity> implements BaseDAO<T> {
   ...

    public void doSomething(Class<T> clazz) {
        log.debug("class name: " + clazz.getName());
        ...
    }

   ...
}
```

That log prints what I'm looking for, let's say *com.xyz.Customer*.

But that logging line above is just for illustration.  In the app, I'm using an aspect to handle logging.  And in that aspect, I'm recording arguments.  So in my `@Before` advice, I have some code like this:

```
...
Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
for (Object o : args) {
    ...
    log.debug("class name: " + o.getClass().getName());
    ...
```

And when that runs against `clazz` in BaseDAOImlp's `doSomething()`, it logs as *java.lang.Class*.

So, while understanding that generics are implemented via type erasure, I don't understand why I see *com.xyz.Customer* with the `getName()` call in `doSomething()`, but *java.lang.Class* in the aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example the instance has been upcasted to an `Object`, while in your first example the actual `Class` is provided.  During that upcast the fact that `o` was some other type is lost.

The generics parameters are not considered when calling `clazz.getName()` since the code prints the actual type of the class.

`List<String> list` is still a `List` no matter what genric type arguments the parameterized type contains.  The fact that we cannot determine `List` has a generic argument of type `String` supplied demonstrates the concept of type erause.  Regardless of type erasure calling `list.getClass().getName()` returns the raw type `java.util.List` regardless of the generic parameters supplied.

Comment: yeah, thanks @kevin-bowersox!  your answer led me to the solution i outline below.

Comment: @6cef Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

To log the information I wanted, I use two different pointcuts.  One of the pointcuts recognizes when `java.lang.Class` is the first argument to a method in our DAOs, and passes the argument to the advice.

*(Luckily, by convention in our codebase, when a DAO takes a class argument it always comes first.  This is not a terrifically general solution.)*

Here's what the pointcuts look like:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.dao..*.*(..)) && args(clazz,..)")
public void classyDAOMethods(Class<?> clazz) { ... }

@Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.dao..*.*(..)) && !args(java.lang.Class,..)")
public void unclassyDAOMethods() { ... }
```

And this advice handles each cut slightly differently:

```
@Before("classyDAOMethods(clazz)")
public void classyAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint, Class<?> clazz) {
    logMethodEntry(joinPoint, clazz);
}

@Before("unclassyDAOMethods()")
public void logMethodEntry(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    logMethodEntry(joinPoint, null);
}
```

That `clazz` passed in the first `@Before` has the class name I need for the logs.